# Git pull shared access to multiple users in linux

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Basically  multiple user do git pull into linux server but end upda up with permission denied when user1 does the git clone for first time then user2 tries to do git pull even though SSH key were already generated and updated under SSH key section in Github. So we tried the following step to sort out the issues:

1. created a directory  (mkdir -p testdir
2. get in side the directory ( cd testdir)
3. clone the git repositoy into  testdir (git clone git@github.com:abcd/testcode.git
4. Later set the sharing access at group level (git config core.sharedRepository group)
5. changed the group from ldap to groupname(srvcxxx)
6. later other user (user2) tries to do "git pull" to pull the changes made by user1, we end up with  an error "permission denied"

Appreciate your quick help.

Thanks.

Note: whoever does creation and git clone first time in the linux server, for him/her it will not throw any error while git pull ( i.e, it pulls changes without any issues). it throws an error(permission denied) when other user tries to do "git pull"

Comment: Would suggest either they have separate clones on the server or (more like it), you need to use a service account on the server if you need to share files.

Comment: But service account need an email id otherwise Git will not support. Any alternate solution

Comment: Much depends if any mods are taking place. If you are pulling and syncing, you don't need an email address.